# Python package built with poetry can't find modules

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have built a package with `poetry` using `poetry build`.

This is the structure:

```
├── pyproject.toml
├── ...
└── some_project
    ├── main.py
    ├── options.py
    ├── helpers.py
    └── ...
```

Inside `main.py` I import two modules

```py
from options import some_method
from helpers import some_other_method
```

Which runs fine locally with python, however when built with `poetry` and ran throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/someproject", line 5, in <module>
    from some_project.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/some_project/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from options import some_method
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'options'
```

Also worth mentioning I have this in my `pyproject.toml`:

```
packages = [
    { include = "some_project" },
    { include = "some_project/**/*.py" },
]

[tool.poetry.scripts]
someproject = 'some_project.main:main'
```

Would anyone know what has gone wrong here? Or maybe I have configured something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

you should write `from some_project.options import some_method` in your main.py

Comment: Do I need to do it even though they're inside the same package though?

Comment: yes, you are. it is works locally for you because you run it from directory where all your package .py files locate. If you try to run from different dirrectory it would't work

Comment: if you want build your package you should use absolute or explicit relative imports

Comment: Lifesaver @АлександрНемиров
Ran into a poetry + docker issue with this and solved it by switching the workdir after `poetry install` to `WORKDIR /poetry-project-name/poetry_project_name`